# Highlight a phrase from the question for clarification with a drop down list

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

First: Yes, I know a similar request has been made and responded to before. I think my proposal is significantly different.

Motivation: Make it easier for pre-comment privilege users to answer questions and become more involved in Stack Overflow. Help users who write poor quality questions improve their questions. Increase the number of questions with accepted answers.

Risk: Diverting resources into asking questions about questions, reduce question answering productivity, and spam spam spam...

Theory: Pre-comment privilege users will attempt to answer questions that comment privilege users are ignoring, likely because they questions are of poor quality. Answering the poor quality questions requires either guessing at the asker’s intent or getting clarification. Guessing runs a high chance of the answer not being accepted. Clarifying increases the chance for the answer to be accepted. So, clarification has value, but does it outweigh the risks?

Proposal: Allow pre-comment privilege users to select a section of text from the question, and then associate that selection with one of a number of fixed questions. Examples could include: 'What platform?', 'What compiler?', 'Which version?', 'What is the error?'  Removing the free form component should limit the amount of noise or spam that would be produced by adding this capability; it might even reduce comment usage by comment privilege users.